# Why does Drag&Drop from Engrampa (*.tar.gz content) to Thunar not work?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, thunar, drag-and-drop, gzip

There's a tooltip when dragging (see the screenshot below) but at dropping it flies back to Engrampa and nothing is done: no unzip, no untar, no mkdir(s), no copy, no sudo password dialog, no info/error message whatsoever.

[image: XFCE Drag&Drop]

```bsh
$ uname -v
#40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:25 UTC 2019
```

Thunar 1.6.15

Engrampa 1.20.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your are missing the "thunar-archive-plugin". Try to (re-)install it. If this doesn't solve it, try following the instructions [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/crunchbangplusplus/comments/4ef8ls/how_to_integrate_engrampa_archive_manager_in/).

Answer (score 0):

Did it with:

- ```bash
  $ sudo mc
  [sudo] password for ...:
  ```
- <kbd>F5</kbd>Copy

However, if such simple functions fail silently, I'm not going to change to a Linux desktop once Win 7 support expires. :(

#### UPDATE

After performing (as suggested in [Eroldin's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1195502/562424)):

```bash
$ sudo apt-get update
...
$ sudo apt-get install thunar-archive-plugin
...
thunar-archive-plugin is already the newest version (0.3.1-4).
...
```

there's a message now, at least:

[image: Extraction error]

A `sudo` password dialog, as known from other apps, would be nicer, however. (And the target folder's name isn't `""`, too.)